# Computer won't restart with Nvidia 970 gpu enabled

Tags: windows, boot, gpu

I installed a new 970 on my PC and this works fine as far as i can tell while the PC is on i can game and have never had an unexpected shutdown. However on the first restart of the pc i got stuck in a reboot loop with the PC powering off during windows load.

The computer runs fine in gaming and never powers off during any intensive tasks. The computer boots fine if i shutdown and then power on. The best way for me to make sure it boots is to turn off the driver for the 970 before shutdown and then boot and turn driver on again which i have been doing when i need to restart or windows update.

System is running windows 10 and has a 600 watt PSU with 25 amp on each 12v rail so 300 watt so should have more than enough power. Motherboard is an Asus p7p55d-e lx motherboard on latest bios and an old i7 870 with 8gb ram.

Just wondering if anyone has any suggestions to get me this working a bit smoother or what thought are on a new motherboard however would want a used LGA2011 and am worried i will run into the same issues due to the age of parts and lack of updated bios ect.

Comment: Have you tried it on another computer?

Comment: Yeah worked fine in another PC.

Comment: I seem to have worked around this by disabling automatic restart if anyony else ever faces this issue. Everything now restarts and boots fine everytime.